# React build does not inject CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am creating the front-page of a portfolio website that uses backtracing typing as animation as shown in the attached gif.
[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqycF.gif)
But after building the website using `npm run build` and then `serve -s build`, the website is rendered as

[Current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiGVy.png). The website is available at https://incandescent-gnome-b9470c.netlify.app/ .
For some reason, the website behaves as expected on Chrome for Windows. It does not inject CSS for any other browser including Edge, Brave. The same goes for mobile devices.

```
const App = () => {

    const lines = ["programs.","blogs.","poems.", "stories."];
    
    
     function text_writer(){
        var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
            this.toRotate = toRotate;
            this.el = el;
            this.loopNum = 0;
            this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
            this.txt = '';
            this.tick();
            this.isDeleting = false;
          };
          
          TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
            var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
            var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];
          
            if (this.isDeleting) {
              this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
            } else {
              this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
            }
          
            this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';
          
            var that = this;
            var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;
          
            if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }
          
            if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
              delta = this.period;
              this.isDeleting = true;
            } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
              this.isDeleting = false;
              this.loopNum++;
              delta = 500;
            }
          
            setTimeout(function() {
              that.tick();
            }, delta);
          };
          window.onload = function() {
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
            for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
              var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
              var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
              if (toRotate) {
                new TxtRotate(elements[i], toRotate.split(","), period);
              }
            }
            // INJECT CSS
            var css = document.createElement("style");
            css.type = "text/css";
            css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
            document.body.appendChild(css);
          };
        }
        text_writer();
   return(<h1><div className=" flex flex-col w-full mt-8">
                <p className="text-4xl text-gray-400">Hi, I'm</p>
                <h1 className="text-6xl font-bold">Siddhant Shah</h1>
                 <h4 className='text-4xl '>and I write <span
                    className="txt-rotate"
                    data-period="200"
                    data-rotate={lines}
                    ></span></h4>
                </div></h1>);
        
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This is the code, I am also using TailWind for the CSS, I am unsure if it might be contributing to the problem.

Comment: On my end, the current website is working properly as the expected behavior you provided. I guess you used a CSS that is not currently supported yet with the current version of the browser you are using. Try updating those browsers.

Comment: Awesome! Could you please confirm the browser and os? I am encountering the same issue on mobile devices as well.

Comment: I tested your portfolio in Chrome, Explorer, and Firefox in Windows 10 and Android. The layout is intact.

Comment: With the animation!??

Comment: The typing and skills scroll effect? Yes